# Change config file in python without removing commentS

Tags: python, configparser

I have a simple config file like below and i wrote a quote to update the file.

```
 cat /tmp/cfg 
global key = value
section key = val
[section]
section key = val

[section2]
section key =10
```

My code works fine , but removes any comments i have in the file
example if file was

```
 cat /tmp/cfg2 
global key = value
section key = val
[section]
section key = val

[section2]
section key =10
#section key =20
```

The below code is run using command

```
python  newmodconfig  --section all --config /tmp/cfg --key "section key" --value newval
```

My attempt is below
https://pastebin.com/tbL6iNb2

Comment: What should happen if the original config file has the lines in a different order? A comment might later be at a completely misleading position

Comment: I am not sure if i get you correctly ? We are only changing /adding key values , its ok for the comment to go anywhere within the same section

Comment: I have not really looked at your code, and maybe it is not an issue for your use case. What I mean is that it technically could happen that the original config file was manually modified by somebody. If you know that the config file will always be ordered exactly the same way, the whole thing is probably way easier to do. Because then you can just keep track of the line numbers where the comments were.

Comment: a way could be to add a prefix to each comment before reading it, so now everything becomes a key value for parser, but thats an overkill it seems